# Does GT-I8262 Galaxy Core Support OTG?

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go, android-versions

I am using GT-I8262 (Galaxy Core) android 4.1 does it support OTG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this comes up a lot I would recommend an app to check this, like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.tauruslabs.usbhostcheck)

The `GT-I8262 (Galaxy Core)` does **not** support OTG. I cannot locate any custom Kernels that support it either.

There is no mention of it in [the specs](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_core_i8260-5419.php) for the device either.

Answer (score 0):

I used an USB OTG Checker on my mobile (Samsung Galaxy Core i8262) and I get the message "Your Device OS has USB OTG API!"

Comment: Thanks for the detail! Could you please [edit] your answer to include which Android version your device is running? Does it match that of the OP?